# 〜のがほしい instead of 〜たい

Tags: grammar

To start with, I'm not asking about how 〜たい and 〜ほしい (and their derivative forms, like 〜てほしい, たがる, etc etc) structures work. I want to know whether is natural/grammatically correct to say, for example, ラーメンを食べるのがほしいです instead of ラーメン(を/が)食べたいです.

Comment: I can't see a reason it would be grammatically incorrect, but it seems to place an unnatural emphasis on the act of eating itself. Normally someone who "wants to eat ramen" will be thinking more about hunger and the taste of the food, than the physical act.

Comment: It's always best to ask a native speaker or look it up in a trusted source, but if not possible, [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) is a good rule of thumb to follow when doubting between options that have similar meanings. ~たい is a simpler transformation than のが + ほしい.

Comment: English and similar languages happen to use the same word to express "wanting an object" and "wanting to do an action", but they are different concepts.

Answer (score 4):

It's a grammatical sentence but its meaning is totally different from ラーメンを／が食べたいです. It means you want *something* that is related to eating of ramen. It might be a doll that eats ramen or something like a bowl or a spoon with which you eat ramen.

> ラーメンを食べる**の**がほしいです。
> I want **one** that eats ramen.
> I want **one** for eating ramen.
> etc.

Comment: Somebody please stop my brain from considering the viability of building ramen eating robots );

Comment: @Will - [This](https://www.instagram.com/p/CKMZzOBHDNn/?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y=) is the closest thing I found on the net.

Answer (score 2):

ラーメンを食べるのがほしいです is gramattical but isn't a valid sentence for "I want to [verb]".

If you want to find a similar construction with verb nominalization for that purpose, -することを欲する is a valid construction in place of -したい, with the caveat that it's a construction that's too rigid to use in conversation or even in writing. One appropriate context I can think of is some old translation of Chinese literature or Bible.

> ラーメンを食べることを欲します